# Java control panel -> security -> "Edit Site List" is not visible in java7_45. How to make this setting visible?

Tags: list, edit

Java control panel -> security -> "Edit Site List" is not visible in java7_45. Could you please help me how to make this setting visible?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself that, edit site list is introduced in java7_51. So it should not be available in java7_45.